# Как в WPF в Textbox обойти string.Empty?

Tags: c#, wpf, валидация

Есть некоторая форма (её часть):

```
<Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Content="Колонка кол-ва" />
    <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"
             Text="{Binding CountColumn, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />

<Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Content="Кол-во (если нет колонки с кол-вом)" />
    <DockPanel Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1">
        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsCheckedCount, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
        <TextBox Text="{Binding CountNumber, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                 IsEnabled="{Binding IsCheckedCount, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
    </DockPanel>
```

В модели указано следующее:

```
public int? CountNumber { get; set; }
public int? CountColumn { get; set; }
```

Однако в программе если оставить данные поля пустыми, то выскакивает следующая ошибка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему так происходит и как обойти это?

Comment: Потому что пустая строка и `null` это не одно и то же :) Напишите свой конвертер, например

Comment: А вообще, у вас же вроде MVVM? ViewModel - это лишь абстракция View, если у вас `TextBox.Text` - это string, то логично создавать для неё свойство `string`, а не `int?`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@АндрейNOP посоветовал написать конвертер.

Я написал его и все заработало:

```
<Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Content="Колонка кол-ва" />
    <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"
             Text="{Binding CountColumn, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />

<Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Content="Кол-во (если нет колонки с кол-вом)" />
    <DockPanel Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1">
        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsCheckedCount, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,
                  Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=EmptyStringToNullConverter}}" />
        <TextBox Text="{Binding CountNumber, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,
                 Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=EmptyStringToNullConverter}}"
                 IsEnabled="{Binding IsCheckedCount, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
    </DockPanel>
```

Конвертер:

```
namespace Converters
{
    public class EmptyStringToNullConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            var s = value as string;
            return string.IsNullOrEmpty(s) ? null : s;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return Binding.DoNothing;
        }
    }
}
```